# plotly.js - simple static graph is not show but the complicated one is

Tags: plotly.js

Believe me I'm very desperate to ask this question.

Consider these two plotly.js graphs. The top one is a "copy&paste" from plot.ly web-page and  it's not displayed. The lower one, which is generated via php | mysql | json, is shown. I can't comprehend what I do wrong.

Probably it's something very simple and I'm certainly just blind to something obvious.

```
<script>
   var trace1 = {
       x:['2020-10-04', '2021-11-04', '2023-12-04'],
       y: [90, 40, 60],
       type: 'scatter'
   };
   var data = [trace1];
   var layout = {
       height: 400,
       width: 800,
       showlegend: false
   };
   Plotly.newPlot('test_div', data, layout);
</script>      
<div id="test_div">HERE<br></div>

<script>
   var layout1 = {
     height: 400,
     width: 800,
     margin: {
               l: 30,
               r: 0,
               b: 20,
               t: 10,
               pad: 0 
     },
     showlegend: true,
     displayModeBar: false,
     legend: {
       x: 0.075,
       y: .9,
       bgcolor: "#E2E2E2",
       bordercolor: "#555555",
       borderwidth: 1
     }
   };  
   $.get('json-temp.php', null, function(data) { Plotly.newPlot('chartTemp_div', data, layout1); }, "json");
</script>      
<div id="chartTemp_div" >THERE<br></div>
```

As you can see in figure below the text for 'test_div' is shown but not the plot and everything works as expected for the call to external php-file (which eventually uses 'echo json_encode($data);').

[image]

If somebody could point me to right direction, I would be extremely thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the first call is going through before the DOM is ready. I would try either putting the `<div id="test_div">HERE<br></div>` above the `<script>` or wrapping the `Plotly.newPlot` call inside `$(function() { ... });` to call it only when the DOM is ready.

Comment: I did as you wrote (<div id="test_div">HERE<br></div> before) and indeed worked.